# Nullpointerexception in dialog?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, layout

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

I have a custom [dialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) containing a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) which contains a [listview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html), however I am getting a NullPointerException when trying to set my ArrayAdapter:

```
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.voicedialog);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    dialog.getWindow().setLayout((int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*0.90), (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels*0.90));

    adapter = new MyPageAdapter(this);
    pager = (ViewPager) dialog.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    dialog.show();

    if(pager.getCurrentItem()==0) { //If on first page of viewpager in dialog (this layout contains the listview)
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contactArrayList);
        listview = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listview.setEmptyView(dialog.findViewById(R.id.emptyElement));
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Again, the listview is in one of the layouts in my viewpager in my dialog, with the ID of `listView`

**My question is, why is the listview coming out as null, even though I clearly reference it in the code above, and how can I solve this issue?**

Thanks for your valuable time.

**EDIT:**

VoiceDialog:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="@drawable/round"

    tools:context="...">



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

There are three XML layouts that go into the ViewPager, but the one with the listview is the first page, which is why I put that code in the   `if(pager.getCurrentItem()==0)`.

Here is the `ViewPagerAdapter`:

```
public class MyPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyPageAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }



    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {

        View view = null;

        if(position==0) {
             view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.voice1, null);
            collection.addView(view);
        }if(position==1) {
             view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.voice2, null);
            collection.addView(view);
        }if(position==2) {
             view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.voice3, null);
            collection.addView(view);
        }

        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == arg1;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }
}
```

Comment: You said pager contains the listview. `listview = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView)` dialog won't be able to find it directly

Comment: are you using fragments in view pager ?

Comment: Can we see the voicedialog layout?

Comment: @android_griezmann Then how do I reference my `listview`?

Comment: @quicklearner No, I am using regular XML layouts. I have edited my question with further details

Comment: @Amsheer Sure, I edited my question

Comment: @RuchirBaronia: ListView is inside `pager` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK ListView is inside page one of the `ViewPager`, correct.

Comment: How can I reference it without `null`?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia: And what you are adding in ViewPager? Fragment?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK No regular XML layouts

Answer (score 2):

Because `ListView` is inside `ViewPager`, so need to use current page View from ViewPager to access ListView from it. for this use setTag/getTag method like:

**1.** In `instantiateItem` method of `MyPageAdapter` add tag for each layout:

```
   ....
   view.setTag("current_page_" + position);
   return view;
 }
```

**2.** Use `findViewWithTag` method with `pager.getCurrentItem()` to get current page View:

```
View currentView = (View)pager.findViewWithTag(
       "current_page_" + pager.getCurrentItem());
```

**3.** Now access ListView using `currentView` :

```
    listview = (ListView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Comment: After doing this I still get the error, but it is slightly different

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat

Comment: I am getting `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: @RuchirBaronia: join chat

Comment: Can we continue in chat again?

Answer (score 0):

This xml don't have the listview. You are setting like this `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.voicedialog);`
and trying to get from this dialog. Which contains no Listview automatically it will gets null'

**Edit 1:**
Inside of the viewpager you are adding Listview so you need to add functionality inside of ViewPager adapter.

**Edit 2:**

You need to add these following code inside of your Viewpager

```
if(position==0) {
             view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.voice1, null);
            collection.addView(view);


arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contactArrayList);
        listview = (ListView) view .findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: So then how do I get the `listview`?

Comment: Okay check my edit I posted my viewpager. So how do I reference it now?

Comment: You have R.layout.voice1,voice2, voice3... These contains your listview right?

Comment: No, those are the three pages that are in my ViewPager. Only `voice1` contains the listview

Comment: Check my edit you don't have contactArrayListhere. I hope you can pass it through the constructor..

Comment: That's good and all, but I do not want to only call `notifyDataSetChanged()` when the layout is shown in `InstantiateItem`, instead I should be able to call it anytime I want from my Activity. How can I do that? Your solution does not allow me to call it from activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131762/discussion-between-amsheer-and-ruchir-baronia).

Comment: Do you know how to do it?